# Can't show videotrack - unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: swift, webrtc

I try to show camera video stream for video chat in

```
@IBOutlet weak var localVideoView: RTCEAGLVideoView!
```

localVideoTrack i got from my localStream : RTCMediaStream i created earlier

```
localVideoTrack = localStream.videoTracks.first

localVideoTrack.add(self.localVideoView)
```

After that i got error

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView renderFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

i am using  'GoogleWebRTC'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In future, please take time to format any code in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder / Storyboard, make sure you have set the class of localVideoView to `RTCEAGLVideoView`.

The IBOutlet does not check the class of localVideoView, so if it is not the correct class, then there will be runtime errors.

Comment: in storyboard i have set the class of localVideoView to RTCEAGLVideoView

Comment: that does not help

Comment: I sloved this problem by re-installing  'GoogleWebRTC' pod